# Two IPv6 global unicast addresses on the same interface (stateless and stateful)

Tags: ipv6, protocol-theory, ip-address, rfc, dhcpv6

Can I assign two global unicast address to the same interface, one obtained via stateful addressing (DHCPv6) and the other one via SLAAC (eui-64)?

According to the RFC-4862:

> Both stateless address autoconfiguration and DHCPv6 may be used
>   simultaneously.

But, this means on the same machine, or on the same network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically, you can assign any number of IPv6 addresses to a single interface. Practically, each OS has a limit, but the limit is far more than two. Each IPv6 interface will normally have a link-local, and a global address assigned, and you can assign other global or ULA addresses, in the same or different networks via combinations of stateful and stateless configurations.

Answer (score 1):

> > Both stateless address autoconfiguration and DHCPv6 may be used
> > simultaneously.

> But, this means on the same machine, or on the same network?

It means on the same machine; more specifically, per-interface. As Ron suggested, the standards don't place restrictions here.

This leads to a related question on source address selection for outbound traffic. Often, you don't have to pay attention, but there's more in in [rfc5014](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5014) [rfc6724, section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6724#section-5).